# Newbie to clojure, trying to understand an expression

Tags: clojure

I'm new to clojure, can you explain what this means?

```
(defonce ^:dynamic *some-var1* nil)
```

I understand the "defonce", but not the rest of the expression. What's "^"? What's "dynamic"? **And especially what are "*" in the variable name?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `defonce` macro (like many others) allows you to specify some metadata as a first argument. This metadata is often used to give hints to the compiler about the way the symbol is going to be used.

In this case, the `^:dynamic` metadata keyword is provided, letting the compiler know that this symbol should be optimized for being dynamically rebound at runtime with the [`binding` form](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/binding).

The asterisks are just a convention to let other developers know that the symbol is not bound in the regular way. They are there to draw attention to the fact that it might not work in the way you expect it to.

For instance, a `binding` form is thread local and the symbol is only rebound within the scope of the form.

```
(defonce ^:dynamic *my-var* false)

(binding [*my-var* true] *my-var*) ;; true

*my-var* ;; false
```

An attempt to access the value of `*my-var*` from outside the binding might not return the value that you are expecting.

Because this form has been denoted with the `*special-var*` convention, we know not to expect the normal behaviour and can read the documentation or study the code before referencing the symbol elsewhere.

Comment: **we know not to expect the normal behaviour and can study the code first before using the symbol elsewhere.** -- is it a recommendation? What if it were a closed-source library?

Comment: If it's a closed source library, you can read the documentation. If it's a closed source library using `*special-vars*` and there is no documentation, you should probably think about using something else.

Comment: **we know not to expect the normal behaviour and can study the code first before using the symbol elsewhere.** -- is it a recommendation?

Comment: Yes, it's recommended that you understand why the symbol has been given special behaviour before you use it.